# :counter_cache => true for storing sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, counter-cache

I have the table `users` and `scores`.
Here are the associations:

```
belongs_to :user #score model
has_many :scores #user model
```

The table `users` has the column called `scores_count`. In this column I store the sum of all values in the table `scores`.

I wanted to use this way for storing the sum of all `scores` in the column [`scores_count: :counter_cache => true`](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column?view=asciicast)

But `:counter_cache => true` saving only the count of rows in the table `scores`. Is there any similar method for storing the sum of all values from the table `scores`? Or this task I have to implement by myself?

Comment: You could just add a callback..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You'll have to implement it yourself. Counter-cache is for storing the number of associated records only. You could implement it using a callback on `Score` to update the associated `User`. See also [How can I cache a calculated column in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181090/how-can-i-cache-a-calculated-column-in-rails)

Further, unless you have noticeable performance issues with summing each time, avoid using a cache like this. It's just something that can easily go wrong and get out-of-date. It's not worth the trouble if you don't really need it.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the info. I'd like to ask just - is in this case better to do it with a method (I save the new record to **scores** table and then I will run the method for recounting all the associated values in the **scores** table and save the amount into the **users** table) or through **callback**, as you mentioned above (I didn't work with callback yet)? Which variant is better/faster?

Comment: Callback. You could set a callback for any save action on the record, instead of having to deal with calling some method on each action manually. Callbacks are seamless and less error-prone.

Comment: `Further, unless you have noticeable performance issues with summing each time, avoid using a cache like this.` what if I want to sort the active records using that calculated value? any tips for that? @AndrewMarshall

Answer (score 11):

You could use [counter_culture](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture#totaling-instead-of-counting) gem.

```
class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  counter_culture :user, column_name: 'scores_sum', delta_column: 'score_value'
end
```

Comment: Hi Denis! I checked out the counter_culture gem and it seems this only supports 1 column am I right?

I have multiple associations which have a "costs" column and I would like to combine multiple association sums of "costs" inside 1 column on the parent association. Do you know if this is possible with counter_culture? I checked the specs but nothing indicates something like this is possible.

Comment: @Jens, I wasn't using Rails for more than six ears now, can't answer your question, sorry.

Comment: No worries! I wrote my own implementation of caching specific columns for my scenario.

I noticed I couldn't use counter culture for the problem I had since some columns needed different calculations based on a given type. Which counter culture doesn't support.