# Rails - counter_cache for total sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have `Transactions` table which is the M:M table between `Users` and `Products`.

```
class Transaction
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product, counter_cache: :transactions_count
end
```

Inside Transaction table, I have `quantity` column.

While inside Products, I have `transactions_count` which stores how many times this product has been purchased.

But that counter cache only count the **number of rows**. Is there a way to count the **sum of quantity**?

I know I can use something like `after_save :update_count`, but is there a **Rails convention** that when followed will automate this task?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [:counter\_cache => true for storing sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019253/counter-cache-true-for-storing-sum)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've personally found `counter_cache` to be very unreliable (giving negative values etc), and tend to shy away until it's improved

Something you may be interested in:

---

**Alias Column**

[We wanted to do something similar (pull from join model)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250636/rails-scoping-for-has-many-through-to-access-extra-data), and found a reliable way was to use an SQL Alias Column:

```
#app/models/user.rb
has_many :transactions
has_many :products, -> { select("#{User.table_name}.*, SUM(#{Transaction.table_name}.quantity) AS total") }, through: :transactions, dependent: :destroy
```

This may need some work, but will help#

---

**ActiveRecord Association Extension**

After discovering the [`.delegate`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) method, I wanted to see if we could implement something similar for join models. 2 weeks later, we had it working:

```
#app/models/message.rb
Class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :image_messages
   has_many :images, through: :image_messages, extend: ImageCaption
end

#app/models/concerns/image_caption.rb
module ImageCaption

    #Load
    def load
        captions.each do |caption|
            proxy_association.target << caption
        end
    end

    #Private
    private

    #Captions
    def captions
        return_array = []
        through_collection.each_with_index do |through,i|
            associate = through.send(reflection_name)
            associate.assign_attributes({caption: items[i]}) if items[i].present?
            return_array.concat Array.new(1).fill( associate )
        end
        return_array
    end

    #######################
    #      Variables      #
    #######################

    #Association
    def reflection_name
        proxy_association.source_reflection.name
    end

    #Foreign Key
    def through_source_key
        proxy_association.reflection.source_reflection.foreign_key
    end

    #Primary Key
    def through_primary_key
        proxy_association.reflection.through_reflection.active_record_primary_key
    end

    #Through Name
    def through_name
        proxy_association.reflection.through_reflection.name
    end

    #Through
    def through_collection
        proxy_association.owner.send through_name
    end

    #Captions
    def items
        through_collection.map(&:caption)
    end

    #Target
    def target_collection
        #load_target
        proxy_association.target
    end

end
```

This basically concatenates attributes from our join model (`image_messages`) to the parent object (`image`). You could use it to sum up your `quantity` in your `proxy_association` through collection, appending to each `product` the user has

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But from what I understand, it counts the quantity every time we query the database? Will that consume memory or negligible?

Comment: Yep it will consume memory & add extra time. It's only a recommendation to help give some ideas. The `counter_cache` is just a column in the db with a number in it; so I suppose you could use your idea for `after_update` to update the quantity column :)

Comment: Thanks for that, I guess I will go with using `after_update` or `after_save`

Comment: Np! We actually made another script which uses [ActiveRecord Association Extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions) to manipulate the `proxy_association` object. Can post the code if you want -- this uses memory, not SQL

Comment: If you're willing, you can post it here :)

Comment: Sure, let me post for you

Comment: it's been years since you answered, anyone could give updates? are active_record callbacks and counter cache already good for this tasks now?